Infimum of a set - Value at Risk
I don't understand these semantics. Can somebody tell me with easy words and some other examples how to understand this last equation and why it equals 0?
How to understand this colon after variable 'x' and this whole inequality inside aswell as taking infimum from it? Thanks in advance for help and clean explanation.


This is an example of set-builder notation.  It is universal in mathematics.  "Infimum" is a formal name for the greatest lower bound of any (nonempty) set of real numbers.

The colon means the condition, i.e. "such that" in plain English. The definition of the value-at-risk is such an amount X that with probability $\alpha$ the portfolio loss is equal to or greater than X. It's just a fancy way of reporting the quantile function of the probability distribution of losses.
In your example, the probability distribution of losses is discrete, Bernoulli with p=0.8%. If you look at inverse CDF of this distribution, then it is equal to zero at $\alpha=1\%$, hence the VaR=0. If you were looking at $alpha=5\%$, then VaR=100,000$ - mind the sign!

Yes, the generalized inverse of the CDF which uses the infinum can also be found in the context of copula theory.

@Galen, value-at-risk framework is univariate: the distribution is constructed of losses in currency, which is univariate.
